# how to compare two objects of another class?

Tags: java

I have to write a method which will take 2 objects P1 and P2 as arguments (objects of class CP)
and return -1 is P1 is smaller than P2, 1 if P1 is greater than P2 and 0 if P1 == P2

My main code is

```
public class PostCodeSorter 
{
    public void sortPostcodeString(String p1, String p2)
    {
        String area1=null,area2=null;
        int regionCode1=0,regionCode2=0;
        String subRegionCode1=null,subRegionCode2=null;
        int sectorCode1=0,sectorCode2=0;
        String unit1=null,unit2=null;

        CPW_PostCode P1=new CPW_PostCode();
        CPW_PostCode P2=new CPW_PostCode();

        String[] PostCodeSepeat_p1 = postcodeSeperator(p1);

        area1 = PostCodeSepeat_p1[0];
        if(PostCodeSepeat_p1[1]!=null) 
            regionCode1 = Integer.parseInt(PostCodeSepeat_p1[1]);
        else 
            regionCode1=0;
        subRegionCode1 = PostCodeSepeat_p1[2];
        if(PostCodeSepeat_p1[3]!=null) 
            sectorCode1 = Integer.parseInt(PostCodeSepeat_p1[3]);
        else
            sectorCode1=0;
        unit1 = PostCodeSepeat_p1[4];

        P1.setArea(area1);
        P1.setRegionCode(regionCode1);
        P1.setSubRegionCode(subRegionCode1);
        P1.setSectorCode(sectorCode1);
        P1.setUnit(unit1);


        String[] PostCodeSepeat_p2 = postcodeSeperator(p2);

        area2 = PostCodeSepeat_p2[0];
        if(PostCodeSepeat_p2[1]!=null) 
            regionCode2 = Integer.parseInt(PostCodeSepeat_p2[1]);
        else 
            regionCode2=0;
        subRegionCode2 = PostCodeSepeat_p2[2];
        if(PostCodeSepeat_p2[3]!=null) 
            sectorCode2 = Integer.parseInt(PostCodeSepeat_p2[3]);
        else
            sectorCode2=0;
        unit2 = PostCodeSepeat_p2[4];

        P2.setArea(area2);
        P2.setRegionCode(regionCode2);
        P2.setSubRegionCode(subRegionCode2);
        P2.setSectorCode(sectorCode2);
        P2.setUnit(unit2);

        // Afshan - write a procedure which will take P1 and P2 as arguments and return -1 is P1 is smaller than P2, 1 if P1 is greater than P2 and 0 if P1 == P2

        result = comparePostalCode(P1,P1);
        //System.out.println("P1 is:"+P1);
        System.out.println("RESULAT IS:"+result);
        System.out.println("Area1            : " + area1);
        System.out.println("regionCode1      : " + regionCode1);
        System.out.println("subRegionCode1   : " + subRegionCode1);
        System.out.println("sectorCode1      : " + sectorCode1);
        System.out.println("unit1            : " + unit1);

        System.out.println("Area2            : " + area2);
        System.out.println("regionCode2      : " + regionCode2);
        System.out.println("subRegionCode2   : " + subRegionCode2);
        System.out.println("sectorCode2      : " + sectorCode2);
        System.out.println("unit2            : " + unit2);

    }
public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        try 
        {
                PostCodeSorter p = new PostCodeSorter();
        //p.Sort();
        p.sortPostcodeString("M1 1AA","EC1A 1BB");
    } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The CP program is

```
public class CP 
{
    static String area;
    int regionCode;
    String subRegionCode;
    int sectorCode;
    String unit;
    public String getArea()
    {
        return area;
    }
    public void setArea(String area)
    {
        this.area = area;
    }
    public int getRegionCode() {
        return regionCode;
    }
    public void setRegionCode(int regionCode)
    {
        this.regionCode = regionCode;
    }
    public String getSubRegionCode()
    {
        return subRegionCode;
    }
    public void setSubRegionCode(String subRegionCode)
    {
        this.subRegionCode = subRegionCode;
    }
    public int getSectorCode() 
    {
        return sectorCode;
    }
    public void setSectorCode(int sectorCode)
    {
        this.sectorCode = sectorCode;
    }
    public String getUnit()
    {
        return unit;
    }
    public void setUnit(String unit) 
    {
        this.unit = unit;
    }

}
```

Am confused.. anyone can help me...!!!

Comment: And what's the criteria to decide if one instance of CP is bigger than another instance ? by `area` ?

Comment: I have to print the small one

Comment: Have `CP` implement `Comparable`.

Comment: No.. 
public static int comparePostalCode(CPW_PostCode P1, CPW_PostCode P2) 
 {
System.out.println("UNIT :"+P1.getUnit().compareTo(P2.getUnit()));
}
Am tring like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My GUESS:
 According to my inspilation from the line 'result = comparePostalCode(P1,P1);' of your code, you may use postal(ZIP) codes for comparison.

'regionCode' and 'sectorCode' may represent first 5 digits and additional 4 digits of USA's ZIP code.

In this interpretaion, the White house (zip:20500) is smaller than a hotel in Waikiki, Hawaii (zip:96815).

Code to compare two  objects of class CP will be as follows:

```
public int comparePostalCode(CP p1, CP p2)
{
    int reg1,sec1,reg2,sec2; /* region codes and sector codes */

    /* extract region code from arguments */
    reg1 = p1.getRegionCode();
    reg2 = p2.getRegionCode();
    if (reg1<reg2)
        return -1; /* p1 is smaller than p2 by region code*/
    else if (reg1>reg2)
        return 1; /* p1 is larger than p2 by region code*/
    else
    {
        sec1=p1.getSectorCode();
        sec2=p2.getSectorCode();
        if (sec1<sec2)
            return -1; /* p1 is smaller than p2 by sector code*/
        else if (sec1>sec2)
            return 1; /* p1 is larger than p2 by sector code*/
        else
            return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: It is fine for region code and sector code. But for area?? it should check everything @ Fumu

Comment: I have no idea about 'area', 'subreasionCode' and 'unit' BECAUSE YOU DID NOT EXPLAIN about them!  You had not explain how to compare two data also.   I COULD NOT ANSWER because of lack of information, so I GUESSED.

Answer (score 2):

You need to compare two objects based on certain set of parameters, can be one or many.

Java API does provides such Interfaces [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) and [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html)

Please refer for examples [here](http://www.programcreek.com/2011/12/examples-to-demonstrate-comparable-vs-comparator-in-java/) and [here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-object-sorting-example-comparable-and-comparator/)

Answer (score 0):

You want to compare 2 objects.
That's why natural ordering is not possible.
You can sort based on certain property as you mentioned that unitId.

Java collection API has already Comperable and Comperator interface for this. Both have method compareTo and compare respectively that will give you output based on your requirements